# count key length php

Tags: php, arrays, key

I can't find anywhere how to make an array with the keys and the character length of that key.

Example:

```
<?php
$array = array("ab" => 145, "bassfasdf" => 13, "cdfsa" => 2684);


print_r($array);
?>
```

I would like it to output this:

```
Array
(
    [ab] => 2
    [bassfasdf] => 9
    [cdfsa] => 5
)
```

Does anyone have any idea on how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$array = array("ab" => 145, "bassfasdf" => 13, "cdfsa" => 2684);
foreach ($array as $key => &$value) {
   $value = strlen($key);
}
```

Comment: I feel such a noob right now. Thanks man! I am using this to make an example on how to make a text file smaller by replacing large and frequent words with 1-char symbols.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a shorter way:

```
$result = array_combine($keys=array_keys($array), array_map('strlen', $keys));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `array_map` function, or a foreach loop as shown below:

```
$array = array("ab" => 145, "bassfasdf" => 13, "cdfsa" => 2684);
$keyLengths = array();
foreach ($array as $key=>$value)
{
    $keyLengths[$key] = strlen($key);
}
```